# How could I pass values from a file to another in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a page with a DatePicker that returns me a range of dates that I'll use as params to a POST to a WebService. But how could I keep this date value in another page? 
I make the POST in another post and need the values from the DatePicker and I didn't figure it out how could I use router to keep the value.

What I'm doing now:

```
this.$store.state.primeiraData = this.primeiraData;


sendRequest() {
    var request = require("request");

    var options = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://XXX.xxx.X.Xx:8000/XxxXxxX",
      qs: { datade: this.$route.params.firstDate, dataate: this.$route.params.secondDate },
      headers: {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: { datade: this.$route.params.firstDate, dataate: this.$route.params.secondDate },
      json: true
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log("return do post pro WS", body);
    });
},
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Can you specify if your pages are loaded through router-view (like SPA) or they are loaded completely independently?

Comment: All pages are views of the same project. (This answer your question?)

Answer (score 0):

If you using SPA then put values to $store. If you using redirection then store value in `localStorage` via `localStorage.setItem()` and access it on another page using `localStorage.getItem()`. All should be done in `saveRequest()` method.

Comment: See my code until now: https://jsfiddle.net/zcnkb2j3/
I'm trying to use vuex to save the value, but IDK why the store aren't getting the values